# Word describing an object that becomes a part of someone’s body? Like a plant putting roots in the ground

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

What do you call it when an object becomes part of someone’s body? Like they fuse together, sort of like a plant putting roots in the ground but permanent, “two become one” sort of thing?

Comment: Welcome to ELL SE! Did you take the tour? I highly recommend it! What did Googling words and phrases such as *fuse together* or *join* tell you? Did you try mix, blend, adapt, or absorb?

Comment: I tried, it’s more like if a person puts on a glove and the glove becomes  their skin, but, not just their skin, it’s like another layer to the hand witch is part of the body

Comment: Kind of like Brad's answer below?, science fiction. Which "A plane growing roots' in title sounds like.

Comment: Also sounds like you are talking about a joining of two distinct things. Living and non-living in which science fiction gave us cybernetic organisms or cyborgs. Such as Terminators and Borg drones.

Comment: In which case have you considered assimilate?

Comment: I think I found it, which is better, merge or combine?

Comment: I won't answer that in comments. I am providing an explanation and my own possible answer, to be fair to Brad's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct term to use for this is a [graft](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/graft). The term was originally used in horticulture, where a part of one plant is grafted onto another. One particular application is that most grapes are produced on [vines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_grapevines) where the [scionwood](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/scion-wood) of one species is grafted onto rootstock of a different species.

In recent years, the term has also been used in surgery, where skin or bone from one part of the body is grafted onto another.

Answer (score 0):

> "when an object becomes part of someone’s body? Like they fuse together" for example if a person puts on a glove and the glove becomes their skin,

As far as I am aware this only exists in science fiction.

People have *skin grafts* but that is not quite the same. Amputees have prosthetics but again this does not fit your description. Maybe the nearest would be if you were to have some sort of a *growth or canker*.

So if we are back to science fiction I would suggest

> Morph, Transform, Transformation, Merge or Meld.

Of course if it's science fiction you could make your own word

> His *Meldamorphorical Nano Skin*  rebuffed the radium particles being blasted his way from the decaying Neutron Star.

Comment: In the old hulk movie from 2008( I think) his father gains the power to transform into materials upon contact with them, he can then make those materials parts of his body, what I’m looking for is the same process minus the transformation power edit: thanks to Brad in the comments I found it

Answer (score 0):

Going from recent comments: an explanation.

[Merge](https://www.google.com/search?q=Merge&oq=Merge&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [combine](https://www.google.com/search?q=combine&safe=strict&ei=EZfGYPz_NPaIwbkP_uKuqAk&oq=Combine&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIICAAQsQMQkQIyBwgAELEDEEMyBQgAEJECMgcIABCxAxBDMgUIABCRAjIECAAQQzIHCAAQsQMQQzIHCAAQsQMQQzIECAAQQzIFCAAQsQM6CAguELEDEIMBOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoICAAQsQMQgwE6BAguEEM6AggAOgIILlDYowtYorkLYJzPC2gAcAJ4AIABnQSIAdcNkgEHMC43LjUtMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) are similar, in the context of "two become one", but don't quite mean the same.

**Merge:**  two or more items come together to become a third item that still has separately identified parts. *Two lanes of traffic merge together to become a highway with two separate lanes. The robot merges with the human body to become a cyborg.*

**Combine:** two or more parts that come together to become a third item that is typically indistinguishable from either parts. *Flour and chocolate combine to make cake mix. Folklore suggests bats blood and dogs blood combined to create the first werewolves.*

Comment: If 'merge' is your choice accept Brad's answer. Not mine.